How to properly run Python multiprocessing pool inside larger loop and shut it down before next loop starts
I have a large script where I am processing terabytes of weather/climate data that comes in gridded format.  I have a script that uses an outer loop (over years - 1979 to 2024), and for each year, loops over each month (1 - 12), as data for each month comes in monthly files, and an additional loop that loops over each hour or station, as appropriate, within each monthly loop.  These loops fill arrays that look like [hr, stn, pressure level], or [hr, stn], depending on the variable.  This part works fine.
Once I have the data in the arrays, I am using multiprocessing pool.starmap function to run, in parallel, metpy package calculations that only operate on 1D arrays.  This is where something weird happens.  The program now seems to go back to the outer loop for years, and begins to run "# begin by processing some files that come in yearly format" again.
Here is my code, which is generalized, as I have had a lot of trouble trying to reproduce this error with a much smaller example.
# loop over years
for yr in np.arange(46) + 1979:
    # begin by processing some files that come in yearly format
    
    # loop over months
    for mo in range(12) + 1:
    # open and put data from specific lat/lon points into arrays by variable

        # loop over lat/lon locations ("stations")
        for station in range(50):
            for hr in range(2920):
            # fill arrays

    # go back to working within outer loop (years) for starting multiprocessing work on filled arrays
    with Pool(processes = 16) as pool1:
         tw_sfc_pooled = pool1.starmap(mpcalc.wet_bulb_temperature, tw_sfc_argument_list)
         bulk_shear_1km_pooled = pool1.starmap(mpcalc.bulk_shear, bulk_shear_1km_argument_list)
         many_more_pooled = poo1.starmap(mpcalc.func, many arg lists)
         pool1.close()  # am I closing this wrong?
         pool1.join()   # do I need this statement here?

    # put pooled lists into final variable arrays for use in work

The code works fine until the multiprocessing ends.  From there, it goes back to the outer loop, and begins to read in the next year's data in parallel, with many xarray and other errors (I'm using xarray to read netcdf files).  So, the first year of data processing goes fine, but everything fails for the 2nd year.
My guess is that either multiprocessing isn't being started or stopped correctly in my code, or that it doesn't like being inside a loop, or maybe the problems arise from having 20+ pool.starmap processes.  I don't know.
Any thoughts on what the problem is?

Are you saying that you believe it is starting the next year loop before the previous one has finished? What sort of xarray errors are getting? I wonder if the issue is unrelated to multiprocessing and has something to do with how you're reading in the data (maybe you're leaving some file open when it's no longer needed?).

Also, for mo in range(12) + 1 doesn't make sense. Did you mean to write range(1, 13)? (You might also want to write your year loop as for yr in range(1979, 2025) since that's more standard).

I can check, but one of the problems is that once the errors begin, the only way for me to stop the program it seems is to kill the kernel.  So, I can't take a deeper look into the current state of variables, etc.

You might be able to fix that by temporarily writing your year loop to only loop over 2 years, since you've observed the error in the second year/loop (i.e. for yr in range(1979, 1981)).

Yes, I'm trying that.  I'm only using 2 years and even just doing January in each year.

Well, pool1.close(), pool1.join(), and pool1.terminate() are not closing the pool.  I have to use del pool1 to shut it down, it seems.

That seems strange. del doesn't actually force the object to be deleted immediately.

I'll try one more time with pool1.close() and then deleting the object.   Thank you for your help here.

It is almost inconceivable that the functions close, join and terminate of Pool can behave as you describe.  They've all been around for years.  The function join will wait for all the worker processes to finish, so your program will halt there until the work of the Pool is complete.  The Pool context manager will call terminate, so your program will not continue beyond the with: block until the Pool is closed.  What makes you think that the Pool is not closed before the next iteration of the outer loop?  Can you just insert a couple of simple print statements to verify the program flow?

You're using starmap() which is synchronous - so, no need for the close/join sequence. How many CPUs do you have available? Presumably you have 16 (or more) otherwise your Pool constructor could lead to contention during running of the various instances of mpcalc.wet_bulb_temperature() and mpcalc.bulk_shear()

@Paul Cornelius.  I don't know what to tell you.  I've tried inserting print statements, but they are useless as the program console (spyder) constantly prints errors.  As far as why I think the pool is not closing - the program works fine w/o the pool., the files it's opening in the 2nd year are often opened more than once, which only makes sensse in my view if more than one process is trying to open the same file, and the speed at which these files are being opened is extremely fast, much more so than one being opened at a time.

@SIHGHUP.  Yes, I have 32 cores.  With starmap, do I need to use the with.... statement, then?  I switched to the with statement because documentation says it automatically closed the pool after it ends.

Something that would help is if anyone knows of a way I can stop the program once errors start without terminating the kernel or shutting down spyder completely with the task manager.

@user8229029 Using the context manager is sensible. You'll need to implement some mechanism whereby the subprocesses can notify the main program that something's gone wrong. Take a look at signal

@user8229029 You said you want a way to pause the program at the error without killing the kernel and you also mentioned that you use spyder. If you know the exact line where the error occurs, you can wrap that in a try/except, put a breakpoint on the except branch (so you'd have except Exception:<newline>pass and put the breakpoint on pass), and run in debugging mode (keep in mind the code runs much slower in debug mode). This approach will cause the code to hit the breakpoint only when the exception occurs.

Edit: I should mention, I'm using pypy.
Funnily enough, I posted about the same problem at around the same time as you! This is my post. You can see in the description that I'm hinting at the same problem as you are, that perhaps the processes aren't being handled correctly.
I took a look in the documentation of multiprocessing lib and saw the following, regarding the Pool objects:
join()

    Wait for the worker processes to exit. One must call close() or
 terminate() before using join().

and also:
Changed in version 3.3: Pool objects now support the context management
protocol – see Context Manager Types. __enter__() returns the pool object, and
 __exit__() calls terminate().

You and I both use the Pool object within a context management protocol using the with ... as syntax. This means that, upon exiting the block, the pool should terminate.
I tried joining the threads after exiting the pool, as the first block of documentation suggested, but the problem persisted.
For me, the problem was fixed by manually calling gc.collect() after the block. So, manually calling the garbage collector may solve your issue, but documentation suggests that we shouldn't rely on this, if my understanding is correct:
Warning

multiprocessing.pool objects have internal resources that need to be properly 
managed (like any other resource) by using the pool as a context manager or by
 calling close() and terminate() manually. Failure to do this can lead to the 
process hanging on finalization.

Note that it is not correct to rely on the garbage collector to destroy the 
pool as CPython does not assure that the finalizer of the pool will be called 
(see object.__del__() for more information).

This suggests that using the pool within a with block is enough for it to be properly managed, but it seems not to be the case in our cases.
Try calling gc.collect() after the with block, maybe it will solve the problem in your case too.

There is absolutely no reason why gc.collect() would resolve this issue. You only need to call close/join within the context manager if you're running asynchronous subprocesses and you're not interested in their return values

@SIGHUP It worked for me, maybe it will work for the original poster too. I don't see how your comment adds any value. I literally changed nothing in my code other than this call to the garbage collector. From my side, I have no reason to believe the problem was resolved by anything else other than my call to the garbage collector. So, unless you can explain how this can happen, again, I don't see the value in your comment. I should mention, I'm using pypy, this could also be relevant.

PyPy may well be the problem. PyPy is not tagged in the question so I assume it's not relevant to the OP

@ Stfeanos. Thank you for the post.  Yes, I've tried close, join, terminate, del, and gc.collect().  I'll probably run it today trying pool.close(), then del pool, then gc.collect().  I know others on here will say that's wrong (and it may very well be), but I'm out of options for now.

@user8229029 Yeah just give it a try, it doesn't hurt. Just for the record, I found out that there may be a bug in the multiprocessing lib in pypy. I found some open issues with other people having the same problem as us. I tried running my script with python, instead of pypy, (without gc.collect()), and it run just fine. So, my guess is that if you are using cpython (normal python), gc.collect() won't help you. If you are using pypy, it will. If you are using pypy, maybe consider switching to python for this task. The relevant issue: https://github.com/pypy/pypy/issues/3154
